# Convert Image to lineArt drawing sketch in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I made a flutter app for drawing tracing in which the user can pickImage from gallery and it is used in stack with camera package :

```
    Stack(
      children: [
         SizedBox(
           height: double.infinity,
           width: double.maxFinite,
           child: CameraPreview(cameraController!),
          ),
         Opacity(
           opacity: _opacityValue,
           child: AnimatedBuilder(
              animation: notifier,
              builder: (ctx, child) {
                 return Transform(
                    transform: notifier.value,
                    child: ImageContainer(
                    widget: widget,
                    isColored: isColored,
                    isFlipped: isFlipped,
                    lineArtImage: _lineArtImage,
                   ),
                 );
              },
           )),
        ],
     ),
```

that helps user to draw sketch behind the camera on paper, and the functionality that the image convert to lineArt drawing sketch.

```
      final bytes = await widget.imageData!.readAsBytes();
      final originalImage = img.decodeImage(bytes);
      final grayscaleImage = img.grayscale(originalImage!);
      final lineArtImage = img.sobel(grayscaleImage);
      final invertedImage = img.invert(lineArtImage);
      final newFile = File('${widget.imageData!.path}_lineArt.png');
      newFile.writeAsBytesSync(img.encodePng(invertedImage));
```

This code convert the image but it have the white background and  i want that is without white background
that user can draw a sketch behind the camera. and also the this code hang the device completely for a few second because this code is heavy.